# is it possible to give dropdown like option inside selectbox in html using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select, dropdown

I have a select box like this:

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I want to make the second option in the list a dropdown and display a few more select options.

Can anyone please tell me how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not using a `select`.  You'll need to write (or maybe find) something that does this.

Comment: HTML select have only one level for option. use `<menu>` and `<li>` elements with css

Comment: @MisterJojo i actually use this inside a form, i need to get the value from the select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a second `select` option and controlling when show or hide it.

Example using pure javascript:

```js
var cars = document.getElementById('cars');
var type = document.getElementById('type');


cars.addEventListener("change", () => {
  update(cars)
});

function update(cars) {
  if (cars.value === "saab") {
    type.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    type.classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="type" id="type" class="hide">
  <option value="x">Model X</option>
  <option value="y">Model Y</option>
  <option value="z">Model Z</option>
</select>
```

---

##### [Edited] Using two `select` with same name and values is possible too:

```js
var cars = document.getElementById('cars');
var type = document.getElementById('type');


cars.addEventListener("change", () => {
  update(cars)
});

function update(cars) {
  if (cars.value === "saab") {
    type.classList.remove("hide");
  } else {
    type.classList.add("hide");
  }
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<select name="cars" id="type" class="hide">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

You can use same name and values, only the **id** need to be unique.

Comment: actually, i want to give same name for all the options in this, so if i use this technique and if i give same name to both select, i think it will cause an issue right?

Comment: You can use same name and values, only the id need to be unique. I updated answer with example.